# CSS unit vw includes width of a physical scrollbar, causing problem for height in vw

Tags: css, height, scrollbar, width

For example: I have an element which takes the full width of the viewport. I want its min-height to be half of its width, to get a ratio of 1:2.

On a 1600px wide desktop monitor the element's width would be about 1583px (monitor width minus scrollbar width), but its min-height would be 800px, because vw doesn't substract the scrollbar's width. So that would not be a 1:2 ratio.

An easy solution would be padding-top: 50%;, but if there's text within the element, that doesn't work. Alternative: a left floating pseudo element ::before with padding-top: 50%; would create the desired min-height in the ratio of 1:2, but that would be kinda hacky.

Am I missing something? Is there any clean way?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is include the following so the default padding and margins given by the web browser are removed:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
```

For the element you want to have 100vw and half height:

```
.half_height{
    width: 100vw;
    aspect-ratio: 2/1;    
}
```

Comment: The aspect-ratio property would be great, but it's so new that the support isn't too good yet: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio
- is there any other way that doesn't require a fallback = double work?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  Width: calc(100vw - calc(100vw -100%));
  Height: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: So width is set to 100% because A-(A-B)=B? Anyway, this is not valid CSS: There must be a space between - and 100%.

Comment: This will fail for nested items with relative positions to their parents since 100% will refer to 100% of the available dimension of the parent, which at that point is no longer the view port. It is incredibly dumb how we have yet to implement a pure CSS solution where we can obtain `100vw` without including the scrollbar width when we already have `clientWidth`